# Unwanted redirect from my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, redirect

first of all i'm sorry if my english is not so good, I'll try to explain my problem the best I can, hope you understand.
I've got a problem with a redirect from my website to a casino page, not the entire website but only a specific page "mywebsite.com/casino-game-online"
when I check the address this will redirect my to another website and than to another, but I really have no idea how to end this link, can someone help me to solve this problem?
Thank you so much

Andrea

Comment: Sounds like your site has been compromised. If you're lucky, you've got a plugin with a vulnerability. If not, cleaning this will be difficult. Start with a [malware scanner](http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/) to traige the extent of your problems.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I imagine that my site has been compromised, but I don't know how to fix it.
I used your tool and find out that there is a  "Website error" a critical one, what are the moves? and if the answer is "destroy everything and rebuild" what is the best way to eliminate all the possibile damaged files?

Comment: Start with [this Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked). It's got a lot of resources and links. I had one of my sites hacked a few months ago. The entrance was through an insecure plugin. Once I deleted that (and changed all my passwords), my site was secure again.

Comment: Thank you again, I'll try and I'll let you know.
Hope to solve this problem as soon as possible